# What is the purpose of WITH options in Sql Constraints?

Tags: sql-server

What is the purpose of `WITH` options (`STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE,PAD_INDEX, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS,ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS`)?

I have the following constraint being applied to one of my tables, but I don't know what this all means.

```
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
  )
```

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: IDK why this question was closed, make perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are not constraints. These are **table options**.
[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can enlighten you, there is a clear and concise explanation for each of these options:

> PAD_INDEX = { ON | OFF } When ON, the percentage of free space
>   specified by FILLFACTOR is applied to the intermediate level pages of
>   the index. When OFF or a FILLFACTOR value it not specified, the
>   intermediate level pages are filled to near capacity leaving enough
>   space for at least one row of the maximum size the index can have,
>   considering the set of keys on the intermediate pages. The default is
>   OFF.
>
> STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = { ON | OFF } When ON, out-of-date index
>   statistics are not automatically recomputed. When OFF, automatic
>   statistics updating are enabled. The default is OFF.
>
> IGNORE_DUP_KEY = { ON | OFF } Specifies the error response when an
>   insert operation attempts to insert duplicate key values into a unique
>   index. The IGNORE_DUP_KEY option applies only to insert operations
>   after the index is created or rebuilt. The option has no effect when
>   executing CREATE INDEX, ALTER INDEX, or UPDATE. The default is OFF.
>
> ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = { ON | OFF } When ON, row locks are allowed when you
>   access the index. The Database Engine determines when row locks are
>   used. When OFF, row locks are not used. The default is ON.
>
> ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = { ON | OFF } When ON, page locks are allowed when
>   you access the index. The Database Engine determines when page locks
>   are used. When OFF, page locks are not used. The default is ON.